# In Mavericks, is it possible to use Enhanced Dictation from the command line?

Tags: terminal, macos, command-line, voice-dictation

A use case is: I have a recording in AIFF or MP3 format, and I'd like a text version of it as Enhanced Dictation would have recognized it if I had spoken it myself.

Answer (score -1):

Copy the MP3 file to an iPod & play it into Dictation via line in source (or the mic?)... Not the answer to your question, but it might work for your task :)

Comment: Hackish! :-) I want to use it from the command line in order to automatise it.